# Setting up a Windows testing lab with VirtualBox in my Ubuntu workstation

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I learned how to clone VirtualBox VMs with this article: http://srackham.wordpress.com/cloning-and-copying-virtualbox-virtual-machines/

OK, in the newest version of VirtualBox the `VBoxManage` command is `clonehd` rather than `clonevdi`, but it works fine. Now I have two Windows XPs running. The problem is:

Each of the VMs seems to have its own private little LAN with the host machine. Both of them have IP 10.0.2.15, and see the host as 10.0.2.2.

I'd like to have both in the same LAN, getting different IPs and being able to see one another. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it myself. The answer was to configure the VMs' NICs as "Host-only" and enable the DHCP server. Caveats:

1) VirtualBox's DHCP server is dumb and doesn't know how to give out gateway and nameserver addresses, so I had to configure that as static addresses within the VMs;
2) Windows XP's firewall has a draconian default setting so the machines can't even ping each other. You have to go to the firewall configuration and enable things.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the bridging network interface to join the virtual machines to your real LAN.  There's [multiple guides](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bridging+virtualbox+ubuntu) on the internet if you need assistance with this.

Comment: I would like them to stay in the virtual LAN, but in the SAME virtual LAN. The network people here would frown at so many bogus MACS emitting from my cable.

Answer (score 0):

I have my set of virtualized windows with a AD server and a few clients in a virtual network. I use VirtualBox and run Vyatta, an open source routing software, assigning a network address of 192.168.5.0 for the virtual network (and 192.168.1.0 for my physical network)

The Vyatta virtualized router has two interfaces, one configured as bridged, and another internal. All the Windows VM connect to the internal virtualized interface, and internet access is provided through the router connecting the two networks.

In essence, I have:

Modem -> Hardware router -> Virtualized router -> Windows testing lab.

Extremely useful for keeping the lab network isolated without any stuff leaking over to the actual production network.